# "code ." command stopped working from Ubuntu bash shell for Windows 10

Tags: editor

I have WSL on Windows 10, and I used to be able to open a folder in VS Code from the Ubuntu bash shell using the command "code ." but this stopped working.

I double checked that "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin" was added to my PATH, but it is still not working. Also, the VS Code command palette does not give me the option to install Shell Commands like I saw in other answers for people who were having the same problem with Mac OSX.

I really like the feature of being able to open a folder from command line -- is there a fix to this, or perhaps even a workaround?